# Eclipse running a web app on an existing tomcat installation

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I have an existing tomcat server running on my local machine that is being started from outside of eclipse. Is there a way to deploy my web app from eclipse to that tomcat instance without having eclipse trying to start that instance of tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using ANT scripts in eclipse which will deploy war file into tomcat directory and tomcat will take care rest of the things.

For those ant scripts you can see this below links

[How Apache Ant deploys .war file to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131462/how-apache-ant-deploys-war-file-to-tomcat)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/423905/tools/automate-deployment-war-Tomcat-through